# Two-column expanding gallery issue

Tags: css, sorting, hover

I am trying to create a gallery page with bios for the leadership at my company. The goal is to have the leaders' image and name on cards in two columns that expand when the user hovers over them to reveal a bio.

Currently, cards in the left column work fine, the cards after them in the stack shift right and down to make room for the expanded card.  Cards in the left column, however, shift down to the next row, which moves the card away from the cursor, so you get this jitter where it's trying to jump back and forth between hover and no-hover states.  Also, ideally, when the user hovers over a card on the right side, the card next to it on the left should shift down instead.  here's basically what code I'm working with for this:

```
<div class='column'>
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<div class='column'>
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<div class='column'>
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<div class='column'>
    <!-- content -->
</div>

<style>
.column {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.column:hover {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I was originally working with grid columns, trying to convert col-lg-6 to col-lg-12 or something on hover, but it got complicated and ugly and I ended up with this solution which is about 73.6% of the way to where I need it to be.  My assumption is I need to have two classes, right-column and left-column and manipulate them slightly differently, but I'm pretty new to this stuff and I'm not sure the best way to go about it.  Thanks in advance!